# How to get current number of opened inotify watches?

Tags: linux, centos, inotify

My system is CentOS.

I'm trying to get this by listing `fs.inotify` variables via `sysctl` call (`sysctl fs.inotify`), but didn't found anything useful, only variables to specify limits.

Comment: I don't think there are any provisions for finding the number of established watches, just from looking at **man inotify(7)**.  The process that establishes a watch can keep track of it, but that's it.

Answer (score 5):

`lsof | grep inotify | wc -l`

`lsof` prints special line for each inotify watch allocation.

See [How do I find out what inotify watches have been registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24994331/639687) for details.